# Freezing HTML table first <tbody> row using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to freeze the header column of html table.

I am using a pre defined table component(i have to use it as per my team) in my application in which i need to freeze the header.

I know it works if i apply position:sticky; and top:0; for the table which has thead tag, but in my case the table header is creating using tbody only as shown in below snippet. Grid always maintains more than 100 rows which always have to scroll.

Your suggestions will be most helpful.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Colored Table Header</h2>

 <table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >ID</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Description</td>
     <td>Value</td>
     <td>Units</td>
     <td>Directions</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody><tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody><tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:sticky` on `tbody:first-child tr td` selector.

```
tbody:first-child tr td{
    background-color:lightgray;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tbody:first-child tr td{
    background-color:lightgray;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Colored Table Header</h2>

 <table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >ID</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Description</td>
     <td>Value</td>
     <td>Units</td>
     <td>Directions</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody><tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody><tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >1</td>
     <td>name1</td>
     <td>Description1</td>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Unit1</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >2</td>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>Description2</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
     <td>Unit2</td>
     <td>Direction1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >3</td>
     <td>name3</td>
     <td>Description3</td>
     <td>Value3</td>
     <td>Unit3</td>
     <td>Direction3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >4</td>
     <td>name4</td>
     <td>Description4</td>
     <td>Value4</td>
     <td>Unit4</td>
     <td>Direction4</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome!!  I Thought of doing it to first tbody in the same way but missed some how, but you got me the right point, Thank you :)